# How to show ionic spinner/loader on top of all pages

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

Is there a way to always show the loader or make it stay when I call it?

I made a public service where the loader is created so that I can always inject and access it on any page.

**This is my code:**

```
public loader = this.loadingController.create({
  spinner: 'crescent',
  duration: 5000,
  message: 'Please wait...',
  translucent: true,
  cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading'
});

public async loaderPresent() {
  await this.loader.then((overlay)=>{
    overlay.present();
  })
}

public async loaderDismiss() {
  await this.loader.then((overlay)=>{
    overlay.dismiss();
  })
}
```

**But the problem is:**
The loader does not stay when the page is programmatically changed.

**What I’m trying to achieve is:**
The loader to be absolute and cover all the automated processes happening under in my app.

**Additional Information:**
I have an inAppBrowser and it covers the loading screen.

Comment: which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: I'm using ionic 4

Comment: Most probably your inAppBrowser is in a different layer than your webview, making the HTML and CSS irrelevant to handle it in this case. You would probably reach a more applicable audience by re-tagging your question to include Cordova or Capacitor, Android and/or iOS communities.

Answer (score 0):

ionic 4

```
async present(){

    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: `Uploading images...`
    });
    await loading.present();
}




dismiss(){
    this.loadingController.dismiss();
}
```

ionic 3

```
presentLoadingDefault() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  loading.present();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Hi @yushin, this is what I did with ionic 4, I just modified some parts of the code that I used but I also tried your suggested code just to be sure but sadly, the inAppBrowser still covers the loader :(

Comment: yeah, the inAppBrowser always takes the top position because it assumes that the spinners and other configurations are done on the other side.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the inAppBrowser part. you can only configure that on the website that you are visiting  assuming it's yours.